# Spree- Which version Support A customer to cancel his order?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, spree

I am using Spree 2.4.1.  From User perspective, i am able to order a product. But being a user, how can i cancel the order.?? Can anyone tell how a customer can cancel the order in Spree. If Spree 2.4.1 version does not support this functionality, then which version of Spree will support? I am using Spree Pay-pal Express and Rails 4.1 version.

Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

As a user, you just empty your cart if you don't want to proceed with your order. There is no need for users to cancel an order themselves.

Admins can cancel orders, and there is a cancel state on the order if you need to build the functionality in, though I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: What if a user has already made some order, and later due to some reason, user wanna cancel that order????

Answer (score 0):

Spree doesn't provide this feature in any version. Only Admin can cancel the order. It totally depends on nature of e-commerce app if you should provide 'cancel order' feature for users. Many of the e-commerce sites provide 'cancel order' to minimize the customer support efforts( cancel order via email or call).